# Add users in groups in a Jenkins Job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am using python Jenkins package (https://python-jenkins.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and I want to add users in a group in a Jenkins Job using this api method. I read the documentation and methods but did not find any way to do so.

Can anyone suggest any way to do this task using this package or any other way to do it programmatically?

Comment: Aren't your groups managed by LDAP or something?

Comment: Yes, it is but I want to add it exclusively.